# How to configure your firewall to allow REST requests from Amazon EC2 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website hosted in the Amazon EC2 which calls a web service hosted locally in my personal network.

I wish to restrict access to my web service using my firewall so that only the website hosted in Amazon EC2 can access it. I don't want to open the web service up to the entire internet.

The website that is hosted in the Amazon EC2 which sits behind a load balancer. This means the ip address of my website can change at any time.

I know you can get the ip addresses via the following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

But these could change and I need to update my firewall again.

How should I configure my firewall to only allow access from my website hosted in Amazon EC2 AWS?

Comment: If you have one instance on your AWS setup, you will need attach a Elastic IP. Elastic IPs are not transient and will allow you to whitelist the IP in your firewall. If you are in a VPC and your instances are in private subnet, you will need to use ELastic IPs for your NAT gateways & you will need to whitelist the NATs. Any request originating from your AWS network will use ELastic Ip as broadcast IP.

Comment: @Shibashis You should write that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one instance on your AWS setup, you will need attach a Elastic IP. Elastic IPs are not transient and will allow you to whitelist the IP in your firewall. If you are in a VPC and your instances are in private subnet, you will need to use ELastic IPs for your NAT gateways & you will need to whitelist the NATs. Any request originating from your AWS network will use ELastic Ip as broadcast IP.

Comment: Thanks. We are not directly dealing with AWS. We are using a platform that is hosted on AWS. I will check with the platform provider to see if this is something they can arrange. I will also have a read up about Elastic IP.